# How to write a program that takes 3 inputs by user F0, F1 and fmax, and outputs all prime Fibonnaci numbers?

Tags: c

This code skips the always the first 2 fibonnaci numbers which are prime (F0 and F1)
I need to write a generalized Fibonnaci sequence that are also prime.
where Fn​=Fn−1​+Fn−2, I know my problem is in the loop, but I am not figuring it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define false 0
#define true 1

int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

{

```
int NN, PN, i, terms;

int F0;
int F1;
int Fmax;
char *p;
terms = Fmax = strtol(argv[3], &p, 10);
F0 = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);;
F1 = strtol(argv[2], &p, 10);

F0 = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);
if (*p != '\0')
{
    return 1;
}
F1 = strtol(argv[2], &p, 10);
if (*p != '\0')
{
    return 1;
}
Fmax = strtol(argv[3], &p, 10);
if (*p != '\0')
{
    return 1;
}
if (argc != 4)
{   
    printf("Error: Please enter only 3 values, for F0, F1 and Fmax\n");
    return 1;
}
if (F0 < 1 || F1 < 1 || Fmax < 1)
{
    printf("Error: Please put only positive values\n");
}
if (F0 > F1)
{
    printf("Error: F0 can not be bigger than F1\n");
}
if (Fmax < F1)
{
    printf("Error: Fmax can`t be less than F1\n");
}
if (F0 < 1 || Fmax > 1000000)
{
    printf("Error: Please enter a value between 1 and 1000000\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I am sure the problem is in here, but I have tried to set terms as Fmax, and I actually saw some codes online that is supposed to have the same purpose.

```
else
{
    if (F1 == 2)
    {
        printf("2\n");
    }
for(i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
NN = F0 + F1;
F0 = F1;
F1 = NN;
for(PN = 3; PN <= NN; PN++)
{
    if(PN == NN)
    printf("%d\n", NN);
    if (NN > Fmax)
    break;
    if (NN % PN == 0)
    break;
}
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int f0, f1, fn;
    cin >> f0 >> f1 >> fn;

    while(f0 <= fn){
        if(isPrime(f0)) cout << f0 << '\n';
        f1 = f0+f1;
        f0 = f1-f0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, an important remark about this problem:

If you want to know if `f(n)` is a prime number, you can use a linear recursion to find a closed formula to know the value. `f(n) = Fib(n-1)*(f(0)+f(1)) + Fib(n-2)*f(1)`

From this closed formula you can distinguish some important facts:

1. If `gcd(f(0), f(1)) != 1`. Then, there are no prime numbers in your sequence (ignoring `f(0)` and `f(1)` of course).
2. If `f(1)%Fib(n-1) == 0`. Then, `f(n)` is not a prime number.
3. If `Fib(n-2)%(f0+f1) == 0`. Then, `f(n)` is not a prime number.

The function `isPrime(n)` is an efficient function that returns `true` if `n` is a prime number, otherwise it returns `false`.

More info about that function, you can search for `primality testing` as [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) algorithm.